# GridView with SqlDataSource Update won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this `GridView` in my web:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ClientGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="id,email,first,last">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                      &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                      &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                            onclientclick="javascript:return confirm('are you sure you want to delete.');" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="first" HeaderText="first" SortExpression="first"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="last" HeaderText="last" SortExpression="last" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:clientConnectionString %>" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:clientConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Client;" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Client WHERE id = @id AND email = @email;"
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE Client SET first = @first WHERE id = @id;">

                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="first" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>
             </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And when i try to excute a update on a row it's stay it the same values and won't Update, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: My guess, with no compiler at hand, is to change DataKeyNames to "id" rather than the composite, comma separated list you have now.

Comment: your update statement expects only two parameter and you are passing 4?

Comment: It's just for my tests... It's still won't working....

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla What you mean?

Comment: My God, just try DataKeyNames="id" in your grid definition instead of DataKeyNames="id,email,first,last".

Comment: Is the gridview inside an update panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the UpdateCommand, the First field is the only one updating.  Is it updating successfully?

I would think that your Update command would need to be "Update Client Set first = @first, last = @last, email = @email where id = @id"

Answer (score 0):

If you want update only first row ,Firstly you should use the boundfield read only ture except first hope this should work
otherwise 
use the advice DavidEdwards